# Fill a vector of uint16_t using a boost::dynamic_bitset<>

Tags: c++, boost-dynamic-bitset

I am creating a program that compresses files with Huffman compression. Originally I was using a vector of uint8_t to store bytes from the file, but the performance was horrible (2 hours to decompress a 74 MB file).
I have decided to use 16 bit chunks to represent values from the file.

Originally, I had this (the input bitset has 520 million bits in it)

```
std::vector<uint8_t> bytes;
boost::dynamic_bitset<unsigned char> input;

boost::to_block_range(input, std::back_inserter(bytes));
```

This worked great, and it filled a vector full of 8 bit integers that represented each byte of the file. The frequencies of each bit are recorded in a vector of integers of size 256. This is running horribly. It takes absolutely forever to decode a string, since the frequencies of these integers in my file are HUGE. I thought it would be better if I used 16 bit integers, and stored frequencies in a vector of size 65536. Here is my attempt at filling my vector of "bytes":

```
std::vector<uint16_t> bytes;
boost::dynamic_bitset<unsigned char> input;

boost::to_block_range(input, std::back_inserter(bytes));
```

The problem here is that the to_block_range() function is taking 8 bits out of my bitset and padding them with 8 zeroes, rather than taking 16 bytes out at a time.

Is there any way to fill a vector of uint16_t from a dynamic bitset in this fashion?

Comment: Have you profiled your code to check where the performance issue is?

Comment: Yes. It occurs after every bit-representation of each byte is appended to the string. This string represents the compressed version of the bitset, but since there are only 256 possible unique values, the frequencies of these values are enormous, which causes the string to be enormous. To decode this string with huffman decoding, it has to be read in character by character, which is what takes hours

Comment: huff decoding should be a simple and fast process, could you explain in more detail what you are doing? I can't understand why the frequencies of your numbers being large is causing a problem. I'm not sure I understand the use of bitset here either, maybe you are using the wrong tools for the job?

Comment: Apologies. I have a massive bitset to compress. I am reading chunks of 8 bits into an integer (uint8_t) and storing all of these in a vector. While reading these in, I increment the corresponding index of an array of size 256 (for example, if I read in 00001010, index 10 will increment). Then, each byte (256 total) gets its own unique identifying code. More frequently occuring bytes get a shorter code, less frequent get a longer code. Then, I read through each byte in the vector and append its corresponding prefix code to a string. Once this is done, that string

Comment: will represent the compressed version of the file. In order to decompress this, I have to read every character of that compressed string and use it to traverse a tree to extract the original (decompressed) value. My issue is that using 8 bit integers means that for a bitset of size 500 million like mine, each one of the numbers 0-256 will occur thousands and thousands of times, resulting in a HUGE compressed string. If I could instead read the bitset in chunks of 16, I could have 65536 different values, meaning my frequencies would be much lower and the compressed string would be smaller

Comment: It sounds like your bitset has very little entropy so is fundamentally not compressible with an entropy encoder. Using larger symbols will probably just make it worse. If you write your bits uncompressed to a file then use a standard compression like zip do you get any size reduction?

Comment: Is that necessarily true though? The bitset is enormous, so partitioning it into 8 bit chunks will lead to 256 unique values, so the entropy will be extremely low. But if I partition it into 16 bit chunks, I have 65536 unique values, greatly decreasing the number of times I have to write each prefix code to the compressed string. And I have not tried that yet, but this is all part of an assignment to implement huffman encoding

Comment: If your data is essentially random then you'll just end up with 65536 values all with equal frequencies and be back to the same issue. p.s the entropy is actually high, that was a typo in my previous comment

Comment: Ah. Sorry I don't understand compression completely. It makes sense in concept, but we've been given this ridiculous set of bits and I'm not sure the best way of compressing it. Huffman seemed easiest, but it doesn't seem to be very good at decompression

Answer (score 1):

The problem here might not be what you think.

In your byte-based approach, adding a `reserve` call is likely to improve things considerably.

```
std::vector<uint8_t> bytes;
boost::dynamic_bitset<unsigned char> input;

bytes.reserve(input.num_blocks());
boost::to_block_range(input, std::back_inserter(bytes));
```

The problem with just inserting to the back of a vector is that the vector will get copied multiple times while it is growing. You can avoid this by giving it enough memory to work with.

Comment: the to_block_range actually runs decently fast. It takes about 30 seconds and I am sure this will speed it up a bit, but my issue is that I have to create a unique binary string to represent each byte. Then, each of these codes gets concatenated onto a string representing the compressed version. Since I only have 256 numbers that can be represented, the frequencies of these numbers are enormous, and in turn so is the compressed string. If I could represent 16 bit numbers instead of 8 bit ones, I would have 65536 numbers that get a code, so the frequencies will drop dramatically

Comment: Basically I need to change the number of bits per block from 8 to 16.

Comment: @ConnorS I suggest you try out reserving space, if you are taking 30s to run this will be a lot faster.

Comment: @ConnorS Is there a reason you don't use `dynamic_bitset<uint16_t>` to go with `vector<uint16_t>` so the copy works?